# convert date difference to real in postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, time

I have a table containing statistics, and would like to calculate
average number of visits of per day

Basically I would like to do something like this

```
select sum(visit) / (now() - '2019-11-21') from statistics;
```

where I would like

```
(now() - '2019-11-21')
```

to be converted to number of days as a real number, e.g. 1.5

Is something like this possible in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXTRACT` to get what you want:

```
postgres=# select now(), 24.0/EXTRACT(hours FROM (now() - '2019-11-21'));
              now              |     ?column?      
-------------------------------+-------------------
 2019-11-22 19:28:32.254199+00 | 1.263157894736842
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get something that is really accurate, you could convert both dates to epoch values (ie the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970), and substract them. Then, you can divide the results by 60 (seconds per minutes, 60 (minutes per hour), and 24 (hours per day).

Like so:

```
(extract(epoch from now()) - extract (epoch from timestamp '2019-11-21') ) / 60 / 60 / 24
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d3a55c458a8c43d43c06994cb4101c31)**:

```
select 
    now(),
    (extract(epoch from now()) - extract (epoch from timestamp '2019-11-21') ) 
        / 60 / 60 / 24 date_diff
```

```
now                           | date_diff        
:---------------------------- | :----------------
2019-11-25 00:26:03.006079+00 | 4.018090348136094
```